# How can I prevent duplicate items on view initalization for c# mvvm type application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm making an application that consists of a blank main view and 2 user controls, main view is only used as a container to switch between the 2 user controls by using MVVM Light messenger to tell the main view to switch which user control is displayed.

On startup I have the UserControl1 displaying.  I have a button that will show UserControl2.  I set up a timer in the Xaml codebehind for UserControl2 that will be used as an inactivity timer to switch back to UserControl1 if inactive.

It is now evident that I am not cleaning up my data properly because after the timer_tick and moving back to UserControl1, I see my timer is still active and ticking.  On top of that, when I navigate back to UserControl2, another timer is created and this keeps happening every time I move to this view.
I'm new to c# app development and mvvm, so I'm still trying to figure out how to clean and dispose of my data, so I'm not sure what a standard practice would be.

Could anybody suggest the proper way to ensure I'm not leaking memory for my views and viewmodels?

Edit:
Here is a section of my code behind that I am currently using

```
 public partial class AddQualityRegisterView : UserControl
{


    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public AddQualityRegisterView()
    {


        InitializeComponent();
        Debug.WriteLine("AddQualityRegisterView Initialized");

                    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
                    timer.Start();


    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Timer Ticked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        var vm = (AddQualityRegisterViewModel)DataContext;
        timer.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine("Timer Stopped");
        vm.ExitCommand.Execute(null);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the System.Timers.Timer component, it implements IDisposable. In that case you'd want something like:

```
using(var timer = new System.Timers.Timer())
{
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Then whenever you exit that using block, the timer will be disposed of cleanly.

Comment: Thank you.  Suppose I do successfully dispose of the timer I am using, what happens to the rest of that view's instance?  Does it remain in memory, or does it automatically get cleaned up because nothing else is remaining?  My unfamiliarity with this is making me think something along the lines of every time I show this view, a new copy of the view class is being created and not going away.

Comment: It's been a while since I did anything with WPF, so I'm not sure if there's anything special with the way it treats its views. That said, so long as you aren't calling a constructor every time you switch views, you shouldn't be creating a new instance of the view. You'd just be accessing the one which was created initially. But I think when you call this: 

    var vm = (AddQualityRegisterViewModel)DataContext;

you might be creating a new view model which could result in a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating a new instance of UserControl2 view everytime you click the "button" to show it - this is not a best practice as far as MVVM is concerned (Though, this is a different story). Given your existing code, I believe you need to remove the handler to properly deal with the timer.

You can remove the handler by:

```
timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;
```

Comment: I've changed a good bit of my application because I realized I was making a lot of duplicate viewmodels with this type of practice
var vm = (AddQualityRegisterViewModel)DataContext; so now I just have to deal with 1 view model per type and now I can just activate and deactivate the timer when necessary.